# Is there a way to open launch eclipse from command line, like vscode?

Tags: eclipse, visual-studio-code, cmd, terminal

I am wondering if there is a command similar to `code .`, but for eclipse.

I'm using a Windows 10 computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the command line lets you open files using the `--launcher.openFile` parameter, and I think it prompts you with the "open projects from file system" wizard when you give it a directory. I'm not sure it works as smoothly since Eclipse lets you use the same binary for more than one workspace.

https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse/OpenFileFeature